# Имеет ли значение порядок объявления JS файлов?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Вопрос по поводу порядка объявления импорта `JavaScript`- файлов. Имеет ли значение в работе программы, какой скрипт в объявлении стоит выше, а какой ниже? 
Напр.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/EditingTemplateWindow.ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/EditingTemplateWindow.js"></script>
```

*UPD1*:
А выражение типа

```
vasia = function() {
     // Вася беги!!!
}
```

является выполняемой частью во время подгрузки скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если эти скрипты имеют выполняемую часть (а не только объявления функций и переменных) то они будут выполняться в момент включения. Если не имеют, то разницы вроде нет (UPD: за исключением случаев когда они имеют объявления с одинаковыми названиями).

```
//script1.js
var a;

//script2.js
function b() { alert a; }

//script3.js
b(); // выполняемый во время включения!
```

Здесь script1 и script2 можно включить в произвольном порядке, а script3 должен обязательно идти после.

Comment: А выражение типа   

    vasia = function() {
         // Вася беги!!!
    }

является выполняемой частью во время подгрузки скрипта?

Answer (score 2):

Да, имеет. В некоторых случаях, программа может неправильно работать или вообще не запустится.
Объявляйте в порядке наследования: сначала библиотеку, потом плагин.

Answer (score 2):

Если `EditingTemplateWindow.ui.js` имеет большую зависимость от `EditingTemplateWindow.js` и наоборот, то имеет!

Еще нужно соблюдать конфликтность работы скриптов, к примеру:

`вася.js
петя.js`

То петя может не работать, а если:

`петя.js 
вася.js`

То все чудесно работает и конфликтов между скриптами нету.